# Setting up domain.com as the same Meteor deployment as www.domain.com

Tags: meteor

For a Meteor JS deployment, how do your point domain.com at the same deployment as www.domain.com?

I have the A record pointing at the same IP address as www., but I'm getting the "there is no site deployed at this address message":

http://emiliotelevision.com

It appears Meteor's servers are not smart enough to make the site on www.emiliotelevision.com, which is working, also work for the equivalent with out the www..

Is there a better solution for this than pointing at another one of your own servers configured to redirect to the www. version?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [CNAME record](http://docs.meteor.com/#deploying) for both www.emiliotelevision.com and emiliotelevision.com that points to yourserver.meteor.com

Comment: doesn't work. Meteor looks up a new application name based on that CName's hostname, rather than uses the one it's pointing at.

Comment: for now I did something not seo friendly, which is do a window.location= redirect from the non-www. host to the www. version. ...I tried a bunch of stuff--I'm pretty sure Meteor is not prepared to handle this yet (on their servers at least).

Comment: They can't do A records because you would have to give them the hostnames, but CNAME would work just fine once you're finished up

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a domain redirect. emiliotelevision.com should redirect to www.emiliotelevision.com.

Now you can meteor deploy to www.emiliotelevision.com.

You may be able to set up the redirect from where you purchased the domain main.